# Are Auth0 tokens different from OAuth2 tokens?

Tags: ios, firebase, authentication, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication

Pardon the ignorance in advance: I am working on a project where our back-end validates access to APIs with tokens generated by Auth0 login. We are in the process of creating the app version for this previously web-only app, and we are using Unity, for which there is no Auth0 plugin. Therefore, I was considering using Firebase for login to generate the proper token and then pass that to our back-end. Given what I have read implies that Auth0 is really just an implementation of the OAuth2 protocol used by *everyone*, I was curious if there are any foreseeable issues with passing tokens in this way to a back-end configured to accept tokens from Auth0.

Comment: Auth0 has JWT `access_token`s too. If it's not JWT then that's probably because you did not set any `aud` (audience) claim. You kind find signing keys in the Auth0 console.

Comment: Thanks, @Dharmaraj, but that's Greek to me. My question is if I log in with Firebase can I use this access token to access an Auth0 back-end, or is the token issued different from the one issued by Auth0.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by 'Auth0 backend', but if you are referring to your server that also uses Auth0 then you can still use Firebase Admin SDK to verify Firebase's ID Token you would have to use Firebase Admin SDK. Tokens from both auth providers are signed with different keys so you need to verify the tokens with their respective credentials.

Comment: This is precisely what my question was. Thank you. So I need to ask my back-end to authenticate with the Firebase Admin SDK if I use Firebase on the app side of things.